# Python 3: use regex with list Windows files paths as strings having a number in specific position

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x

I have a list of Windows files paths written in the following pattern:

```
["C:\\folder\\a-file-001.jpg", "C:\\folder\\a-file-010.jpg", "C:\\folder\\a-file-bigger-001.jpg", "C:\\folder\\a-file-bigger-010.jpg"]
```

The path is built using variables, so I don't declare the original strings, I have access only to the resulting strings and the concatenation of both:

```
path = "C:\\folder\\"
name = "a-file"
file_number = "001"
full_path = path + name + "-" + file_number + ".jpg"
#"C:\\folder\\a-file-001.jpg"
#Only path, name and file_number variables are accessible to me, I don't declare those strings
```

I want to use regex to find all strings that match the pattern "a-file-XXX.jpg", so giving me this as result:

```
["C:\\folder\\a-file-001.jpg", "C:\\folder\\a-file-010.jpg"]
```

I guess I should use `filter(r.match, list)` to do it, but I couldn't find how to do it.

**Edit**: it seems that my problem wasn't only the filter, but the strings I was trying to compare as well: they are Windows paths, and I didn't know that double backslash would require a special treatment in Python.

After trying with the previous example, I understood that I should use `list(filter(re.compile(path + name + "-\d{3}.jpg").match(full_path))`, but because of the double backslash, I can't manage to make it work. I also updated the examples accordingly.

Comment: What have you tried? This is easily achievable by using `A-string-\d+`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

strings = ["C:\\folder\\a-file-001.jpg",
           "C:\\folder\\a-file-010.jpg",
           "C:\\folder\\a-file-bigger-001.jpg",
           "C:\\folder\\a-file-bigger-010.jpg"]

path = "C:\\folder\\"
name = "a-file"
regex = re.compile(re.escape(path + name) + "-\d{3}.jpg")
print(list(filter(regex.match, strings)))
```

`re.escape` will correctly deal with the slashes so that there are no regex metacharacters in that part of the pattern and it is matched literally.

Comment: You might just want to use `\d+` considering there is no indication that the strings will *always* have 3 digits.

Comment: @emsimpson92 In my case, the strings will _always_ have 3 digits

Comment: Then use `\d{3}` instead of `\d\d\d`

Comment: This should work nicely for you then. `\d+`, `\d*`, `\d\d\d` and `\d{3}` will all achieve your goal.

Comment: Hello, I found that this filter works, but also that my problem was bigger than that. I updated the question with new info. Thanks.

Comment: @AlexHall I had to use path as r"C:\\folder\\", apply `replace('+', '\+')` in filename, and use `list(filter(re.compile(path + name.replace('+', '\+') + '-\d{3}.jpg').match, string))` as the filter, then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @ayrtondenner no you didn't have to do those things, you should have used `re.escape` like I said.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a comprehension:

```
l = ["A-string-001", "A-string-010", "A-string-bigger-001", "A-string-bigger-010"]
import re
pattern = re.compile("A-string-\d+")
l = [x for x in l if pattern.match(x)]
l
['A-string-001', 'A-string-010']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the list to get a long string and then use `re.findall` to get all strings matching the pattern `r'A-string-\d+'`

```
import re
strings = ["A-string-001", "A-string-010", "A-string-bigger-001", "A-string-bigger-010"]
re.findall(r'A-string-\d+', "".join(strings))
# ['A-string-001', 'A-string-010']
```